# Maximum Likelihood Normal Random Variables with common variance but different means

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

$Y_1, Y_2,...,Y_n$ are iid $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$

I have gotten down to $\sum{y_i}=\sum{\mu_i}$ through log-likelihood calculations and then taking the partial with respect to $\mu$ but I am not sure what I have found or if I have even found anything.  I have calculated the maximum likelihood for normally distributed random variables that have common mean and variance but not like this problem where the means are not necessarily common.

I am not very familiar with a question like this using the notation of $\mu_i$ instead of just a vector of $\mu$ so I may just be overcomplicating things.  If that is the case I sincerely apologize.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If the $Y_i$ are iid, aren't their expectations all equal?

Answer (score 0):

As such you have $n+1$ parameters to estimate: $(\mu_1,.....,\mu_n, \sigma^2)$, thus you will have to take partial derivatives w.r.t. all of them: 
$$
\mathcal{L}(\vec{\mu}, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{(2\pi \sigma^2)^n}\exp{\left\{-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \mu_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\} }
$$
$$
l(\vec{\mu}, \sigma^2)=-\frac{n}{2}\ln(2\pi\sigma^2) -\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \mu_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}
$$
$$
l'(\mu_i) = \frac{(x_i - \mu_i)}{\sigma^2} = 0
$$
$$
\hat{\mu}_i= x_i
$$
$$
l'(\sigma^2) = -\frac{n}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \mu_i)^2}{2\sigma^4} = 0
$$
$$
\hat{\sigma}^2= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \mu_i)^2}{n}.
$$
To assure that this is a indeed the MLE, you should check that the Hessian matrix is negative definite.